# Radio Button select option with textfield in swift

Tags: radio-button, uitextfield, uialertview, popupwindow, selectlist

Iam working in Xcode11 and Swift4.
I need to open up a popup window with selection list (Radio button with label) on tableview cell did-select,

RadiobuttonImage(not-selected): OptionLabel1
RadiobuttonImage(not-selected): OptionLabel2
RadiobuttonImage(selected): OptiionLabelOther

When OptionLabelOther is selected, then need to show textbox and allow user to type his/her own comments.

I have tried some way with uialertview, but struggling a lot, any reference or samples for this combinations.

### Edited:

I have decided to use a tableview with customcell.
I have worked till checking the cell with "OptiionLabelOther", then returning a custom textfield class.
Here i got stuck up with moving the cell frame to tableview top and allowing user to enter the text.

I have added a tableview with cell (with image and label) to display radiobutton with labeltext in storyboard.
Now i need to show textbox when the tableview cell with label as "OptiionLabelOther", so i added other textfieldcustomcell to the same tableview in storyboard, i have added textfield delegate to my view controller.

### But iam struggling to handle textfield frame and cell has to move top.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally decided to go with uitextview on a separate view over the tableview. Hide and unhide the view based the expected scenario.
It worked